# Get the current_index of the my association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know the index of an element into an association

```
post.comments.pluck(:id)
=> [1, 2, 3]
post.comments.find(2).wich_index?
=> Should be = 1
```

Comment: What is the desired result when `post.comments.pluck(:id)
#=> [2, 1, 2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [find_index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/find_index) method for that:

```
post.comments.pluck(:id).find_index(2)
```

In this case you would get the index of the comment with id 2.